# how to find if the kernel being used is real time or not

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have patched a linux kernel 3.2 with a rt patch and have then installed it. Now in the GRUB menu I am able to select the kernel and it also contains the suffix -rt. But I am still not sure if it actually has real time capabilities. Is there a way to find out if it is a real time kernel or an ordinary vanilla kernel?
Further according to an example in rtwiki, which informs whether we are using a vanilla or a rt preempt kernel.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
struct utsname u;
int crit1, crit2 = 0;
FILE *fd;
uname(&u);
crit1 = strcasestr (u.version, "PREEMPT RT");
if ((fd = fopen("/sys/kernel/realtime","r")) != NULL) {
int flag;
crit2 = ((fscanf(fd, "%d", &flag) == 1) && (flag == 1));
fclose(fd);
}
fprintf(stderr, "this is a %s kernel\n",
(crit1 && crit2) ? "PREEMPT RT" : "vanilla");
}
```

This code access's a file named realtime from sys/kernel, but no such file was created when i patched my kernel with an rt patch.

Comment: `uname -r` will show the kernel version.

Comment: @rakib ya even it shows rt in suffix , but is the method that i used enogh for installation of real time . Now is there anything to be done for activating real time kernel

Comment: because when i try running real time programs, I get error like "sched_setscheduler failed: Operation not permitted".

Comment: @user3351066 i think it's enough and as @rackib say you can check with `uname -r` so you will get something `-rt**` suffix` like `uname -a 
Linux krachkiste 2.6.18-rt5 #3 PREEMPT Thu Oct 06 14:28:47 CEST 2006 i686 GNU/Linux `

Comment: @user3351066 Also note that you must enable `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT` and do some other configuration as per following screenshot http://www.pengutronix.de/images/rt-wiki/menuconfig1.PNG and http://www.pengutronix.de/images/rt-wiki/menuconfig1.PNG and http://www.pengutronix.de/images/rt-wiki/menuconfig1.PNG

Comment: ya thats how i have done it , thanks!!

Comment: `uname -v` shows `PREEMPT RT`. Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55000/checking-linux-kernel-for-rt-preempt-patch/55001#55001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presence of `real time scheduler` and various other dependent kernel option is what makes a kernel real time. If this is the default scheduler selected in the source, then it is real time. You can put some `printfs` in the source to check whether that code is getting executed and check using `dmesg`.

You need to debug the kernel using `kgdb` or other debug tools to see why you are getting errors.